# Web Service error in jqwidgets grid Bind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services

I want to run a sample project from [here](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/asp.net-integration/asp.net-web-service-grid.htm). Its a sample of jqxGrid using ASP.net Web service. But the problem is after running the sample there is no value, there is a parsing problem.

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public object GetData()
    {
        string result;
        WebResponse response;
        WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/sampledata/data.php");
        response = request.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
        }
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(result);            
    }
```

This is .cs code in webservice.asax

And the webservice error:

```
    System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.NotSupportedException: The type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] is not supported because it implements IDictionary.
       at System.Xml.Serialization.TypeScope.GetDefaultIndexer(Type type, String memberInfo)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.TypeScope.ImportTypeDesc(Type type, MemberInfo memberInfo, Boolean directReference)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.TypeScope.GetTypeDesc(Type type, MemberInfo source, Boolean directReference, Boolean throwOnError)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.CreateUnknownTypeException(Type type)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteTypedPrimitive(String name, String ns, Object o, Boolean xsiType)
       at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write1_Object(String n, String ns, Object o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
       at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write2_anyType(Object o)
       at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ObjectSerializer.Serialize(Object objectToSerialize, XmlSerializationWriter writer)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter textWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.XmlReturnWriter.Write(HttpResponse response, Stream outputStream, Object returnValue)
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.WriteReturns(Object[] returnValues, Stream outputStream)
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.WriteReturns(Object[] returnValues)
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.Invoke()
```

I need to know what the error actually is trying to mean? And is there any solve?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you ran the correct sample - ASP.NET\jqxGrid\WebService - Binding? 
You will also need to update the jQuery's reference to 1.10.2 in Site.Master.